# Insert many SQL records with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I use this code to insert a lot data into PostgreSQL table:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\in_progress\\test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            Optional<ProcessedWords> isFound = processedWordsService.findByKeyword(keyword);

            if(isFound.isPresent())
            {
                UpdateKeywordRequestDTO obj = UpdateKeywordRequestDTO.builder().keyword(keyword)
                processedWordsService.updateBySeoScoreUs(obj);
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessedWords obj = ProcessedWords.builder()
                        .keyword(keyword)
                        .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .build();
                processedWordsService.save(obj);
            }
        }

        fstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have too many data to insert and as you can see I first make a select to check is the data available.
How I can speedup the code execution? For example can I use multithreading or there is some other way?

Comment: If each line has unique keywords, you can use multithreading. In addition, what is `keyword`? Is it `strLine`?

Comment: The thing is that I need to make a SQL query for check first.

Comment: Stop processing row-by-row.  Read all keyword from file.  `Select * where in keyword` then batch insert

Comment: If you decide to apply multithreading to your code, I recommend you also check out semaphores in case your code needs to update the same row more than once

Comment: There is no reason to believe that multithreading can make this faster. There is only one network and only one DB server.

Comment: Can you advise some way to speedup my code?

Comment: This post doesn't make sense. The while loop iterates over `strLine` which is never read inside the loop. Inside the loop, there's usage of `keyword` which is not defined or assigned anywhere. What is in the text file? What data processing are you doing before trying an insert? It _looks_ like you could do [upserts](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/) (insert or update). So, do the following in one thread: 1. read contents of file, 2. produce an output file containing all of your "upsert" statements, 3. run that file into Postgres.